# cakephp saveAssociated with different aliases in models

Tags: cakephp, alias

I want to use aliases in cakephp(2.5.3) models which names are different from the name of the related model. The problem occures when I want o save data with saveAssociated method. My models have hasMany and belongsTo relations. When I want to save data it says there is na error. I dig the problem and think that this could be a problem with validateAssociated method which can change $data value or my knowledge of CakePHP is still on newbe level... Can anyone explain me what may I do wrong ?.

My Model A:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'alias1' => array(
        'className' => 'AB',
        'foreignKey' => 'a_id'
    ),
);
```

My Model AB:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'alias2' => array(
        'className' => 'A',
        'foreignKey' => 'a_id'
    ),
    'alias3' => array(
        'className' => 'B',
        'foreignKey' => 'b_id'
    ),
);
```

I try to save data with:

```
$this->alias2->alias1->saveAssocated($this->request->data)
```

Any idea ?

Comment: What's the actual error?

Comment: There is no error at all. Just don't sava data.

Comment: I debug that and found, that validateAssociated changes $data as it becomes an array of one element with the key of alias and values equals $data before change done by validateAssociated. I tried to turn the validation off, but no luck..

Comment: Can you include the data you are saving? The formatting matters too. Also using real names helps everyone, it is easrier to read and avoids find/replace errors.